# What if LiteDB direct and shared modes are used together?

Tags: .net, nosql, litedb

I am using [LiteDB](https://www.litedb.org/docs/connection-string/). What is the problem of using LiteDB and using direct and shared modes at the same time?

Let's say there are processes called A and B. A connected a DB file in the direct mode. Then B connects the DB file to the shared mode. It was expected that B wouldn't be able to connect the DB file, but it could be connected unexpectedly and data could be modified. In order not to cause a race condition problem, does the A processor need to connect in shared mode as well?

I'm thinking about changing it to SQL LocalDB just in case there's an unexpected problem.

Comment: It's not clear if your scenario is hypothetical or something that actually occurred. Is it something you have experienced?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to run both Direct and Shared modes at the same time.

If you intend to share the database (say multiple apps or multiple processes), you have to use the "Shared" mode.